# Can't find 'Android SDK' in preferences - Android studio 2.2.3, MacOS Sierra,

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-sierra, android-constraintlayout, android-sdk-manager

Android Studio - 2.2.3
MAC - OS Sierra

I'm looking for the option 'Android SDK' that should be on Android studio at : Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK.

I know this option was available earlier and one could easily configure it.

Also when I click the icon for SDK Manager on the toolbar, it launches the standalone one instead of loading the SDK manager built in Android Studio.

I need to add ConstraintLayout for my project and as per this link [Add ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) I need to download specific version of the same.

Now give the problem I am facing above, I am stuck on this.

Anybody facing the same issue?

**Actual screenshot,**

[image: Screenshot issue]

**Expected screenshot,**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

This is my screen for setting android sdk in Android Studio with Osx, you can open menu file -> Project Structure -> SDK Location and set android sdk. I hope essert helpful

Comment: Hi Joe Mock,

Thanks for reply, but I am expecting else.. Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Finally Updating to Android Studio version 2.3 solved the issue.

Also, now the 'Launch Standalone SDK Manager' option is not present in this new studio version.

Clicking on the toolbar SDK Manager Icon launches in built manager window.